# VS2012 / IIS7 building website causing conflicts

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have an old website (asp.net 2.0) that is running on IIS7 on a server happily.

I want to make a change to the code, so I have copied all the source code and appropriate binaries to my desktop (running VS 2012).

However whether I am using IIS or the inbuilt webserver I am getting the following error;

```
The type 'foo' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\livesite\169c38ce\cc32b84b\App_Web_qbel5zk4.28.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'foo' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\livesite\169c38ce\cc32b84b\App_Web_m030ztdd.dll'. Using the one in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\livesite\169c38ce\cc32b84b\App_Web_qbel5zk4.28.cs'.
```

This same code worked fine on an older XP PC running VS 2005. I am assuming that this is down to the .net framework, the app pool in iis is set to run as asp.net 2 classic, but the assemblies are being generated under v4 of the framework.

I have tried deleting temporary asp.net files and I am still getting the same issue.

There is only one instance of each of the classes it is objecting about in the project. So how do I fix it so that this works in VS 2012, but still using .net 2.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is a matter of dynamic compilation. By default the "batch" attribute of the "compilation" element in your web.config is true. Something like this :

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" batch="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

With batch="true", whenever a control has to be compiled in a directory, the server compiles all controls (everything?) in its directory.

That may results in conflicts for elements referenced from different locations in your site.

You should try to set batch="false" and to remove your temporary files.
If you still encounter problems, try to do a dummy edit-and-save on the corresponding ascx/cs files.

Hope this will help

Comment: worked for me. Admittedly this is a day later and the PC has been rebooted, but Im putting the solution down to you :)